# TF30063 error with DataSource of Coded UI test in VS2017 (works in VS2015)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, coded-ui-tests

When I use the following on a Coded UI test in VS2015 Enterprise I'm able to connect.

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", 
       "https://<Company>.visualstudio.com/defaultCollection;TestProject", 
       "10216", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)
]
```

In VS2017 Enterprise I receive the following error when running my test:

```
Data-Driven Unit Tests" (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.

Error details: TF30063: You are not authorized to access 
https://<company>.visualstudio.com/defaultCollection.
```

From [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/77486/tf30063-error-with-datasource-of-coded-ui-test-in.html) I got a solution that I should update my Visual Studio. But is there any other way to fix it?

I have the latest update of VS and I am still getting the same error message.

Note : I do have access to the test case and the project in VSTS.

Comment: Remember, when running locally you are on your user. When running on a build machine not. Have you tried to specify your full vsts address? In your question you put it like https://.visualstudio.com - Was this just to prevent showing your correct url?

Comment: yes I have specified full vsts address. Here in question I have intentionally not shown the full address.

Comment: Can you log on that VSTS through Visual Studio 2017 Team explorer?

Comment: If you mean login in visual studio with my VSTS credentials. I have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/refresh-data-caches?view=tfs-2015&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) by refreshing the data catches on my local machine.
To do that, first open Developer Command Prompt for VS an then enter the following command

```
tf workspaces /collection:https://<account name>.visualstudio.com
```

Then it will ask for credential.
Type the correct credential and that is it.

I think problem was that somehow it was not able to assign the correct user(or any user) to the workspace I am working on and because of that it was giving me an error message "you are not authorized to access."